# Loop through range and filter based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Hello I have a sheet called "Summary" in which I have 20 companies in column D6 - D26. I would like the loop to go through the each cell, take the cell value go to a tab called "Tape" filter column Z for that value and take the resulting values from column A to AC and paste it in a tab called "Collateral" Below is what I have so far.

```
Sub Pricing_Export()


Dim wsInput As Worksheet
Dim DataIn As Range
Set wsInput = Worksheets("Tape")

Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
Set wsOutput = Worksheets("Collateral")

Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
Set wsSummary = Worksheets("Summary")

With wsSummary.Range("D6")

Dim qCell As Range
For Each qCell In .Range("D6:D11")

    qCell.Copy

    DoEvents
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    wsInput.Select
    'LastRow = wsMain.Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown).Row
    'LastCol = wsMain.Cells(1, 2).End(xlToRight).Column
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AO$25000").AutoFilter Field:=40, 
Criteria1:=qCell.Value
    Set DataIn = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    DataIn.Copy
    wsCollateral.Range("B1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).PasteSpecial 
xlPasteValues

Next

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: What is the issue here? Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can help you more. As is, you're question is off-topic. Please revise your question and specifically state your issues.

Comment: The issue is that i need some help finishing up the code. As stated in the question i would like to take each cell value in that range, filter a set of data in a different tab based on that cell value and copy/paste the filtered output to a different tab. Then move on to the next cell value in the original range and repeat the process.

Comment: There are some missing lines of code!

Comment: You're asking for a program to written for you!  You already have the pseudo-logic for each step, I suggest you go google for the code for each step and pull it together yourself.

Comment: S Meaden - i dont know how to complete the code, thats what i need help with

Comment: Posting a question here and waiting for an answer will not solve your issue. Btw, I'll give you a hint, dump your `G11 to G20` value in a 1 dimensional array. Then use that in filtering your data by exploring the [`Range Autofilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-autofilter-method-excel) method. After that, incorporate the use of `Range Paste Special Method`. Try something out, if you got stuck due to an error, get back here.

Comment: but you have articulated each step. your plan is a good one.  for each step find a code example .

Comment: i have the above code but it ends up selecting G11 as opposed to D6. Also it doesnt copy the filtered cells. Any help is appreciated.